# Is it possible to auto-rotate UV Islands?

Tags: python, uv

Is it possible to auto-rotate UV Islands with Python? For example I selected all islands and want to rotate them according to their width and length.

I need to:

- get all selected islands.
- get their width and height.
- rotate an island by 90 degrees.

Explanation:

[image]

How do I do it with python?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example image, which islands would be selected for rotation? All of them? The two on the right? The one on the left? It's unclear why you want to rotate them.

Comment: All islands should be selected and rotated according to  their proportions.

Comment: So let's take the image you provided as an example. In that example, which of the three UV islands would need to be rotated? And by how many degrees should they be rotated?

Comment: @Rebellion has been implementing such a feature. It seems he has almost done it.
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340206-Add-On-UV-Align-Distribute

Comment: @Rebellion has implemented such a feature. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340206-Add-On-UV-Align-Distribute http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clgrf0DUvso